# how to upload the image file on mongodb atlas using multer nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multer, mongodb-atlas

"I am new to **NODEJS** I am trying to upload the images on **MONGODB** **atlas** with help of **MULTER** **NODEJS** but don't know to do it  can anyone suggest me the solution."

Answer (score 0):

In `app.js` or `server.js` for file type and storage

```
    const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "images");
      },
      filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        // cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(file.originalname));
        cb(
          null,
          new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, "-") + "-" + file.originalname
        );
      },
    });
```

For filtering whether the selected file is only png, jpg, or jpeg

```
    const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
      if (
        file.mimetype === "image/png" ||
        file.mimetype === "image/jpg" ||
        file.mimetype === "image/jpeg"
      ) {
        cb(null, true);
      } else {
        cb(null, false);
      }
    };
```

Use this middleware in `app.js`

```
    app.use(
      multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).single("image")
    );
```

This is Controller or Route for `req.file` for image in after getting file save this file and creating product...

```
    exports.postProduct = (req, res, next) => {
      const title = req.body.title;
      const image = req.file;
      const price = req.body.price;
      const description = req.body.description;
      if (!image) {
        return res.status(422).render("admin/add-product", {
          pageTitle: "Add Product",
          path: "/adminproducts",
          hasError: true,
          product: {
            title: title,
            price: price,
            description: description,
          },
          errorMessage: "Atteched file is not an image!!!",
          validationErrors: [],
        });
      }

  const imageUrl = image.path;

  const product = new Product({
    title: title,
    imageUrl: imageUrl,
    price: price,
    description: description,
    userId: req.user,
  });
  product
    .save()
    .then((results) => {
      console.log("Product Created Successfully");
      res.redirect("/admin/products");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```